# Extract type guard function type being guarded similarly to ReturnType

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have a type guard function like this one:

```js
function isSomething(object: object): object is { id: string; } {
  return 'id' in object;
}
```

I would like to get the type `{ id: string; }` like so:

```js
type HasId = Magic<typeof isSomething>; // { id: string; }
type NotIt = ReturnType<typeof isSomething>; // boolean
```

Using `ReturnType` I get `boolean`.

Is there a way to extract the type being guarded in TypeScript?

Comment: my knowledge on this is iffy but aren't you coercing the object to be of the type { id: string; } and providing Boolean predicate in your return statement to verify that it holds up to the coercion? So, you should also check whether typeof id prop in object is of type string in addition to checking whether id exists in object. So, later when you call this function in a conditional statement, typescript provides you with the 'id' prop within the if scope. Besides, { id: string } is a type. Can it even be returned from a function?

Comment: @AnjilDhamala I chose very poor words, sorry for the confusion. I am not looking to return the type at runtime, but to infer it from the type of the guard function at type time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [Type Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) (`infer`) to extract the type.

```
function isSomething(object: object): object is { id: string; } {
  return 'id' in object;
}

type GuardType<T> = T extends (o: any) => o is infer A ? A : never;
type X = GuardType<typeof isSomething>;
```